# prevent file_get_contents from other sites PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to prevent PHP's file_get_contents( )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392630/how-to-prevent-phps-file-get-contents)

I want to prevent file_get_contents from other sites to protect my contents not be stolen from other sites.
I found a topic like this but It seems not very clear to me.
[how to prevent PHP's file_get_contents( )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392630/how-to-prevent-phps-file-get-contents)

Any helps?
Example http://ddth.com. You couldn't `file_get_contents("http://ddth.com");`

Comment: There is no 100% reliable method to determine between a 'real' browser, and a spider/scraper pretending to be a 'real' browser. How 'secure' do you need this to be?

Comment: I need only a "normal" secure. Don't need to protected from "pseudo browser" crawl.

Comment: that definition is as clear as mud. Also the linked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392630/how-to-prevent-phps-file-get-contents already answers that and your own question does not explain what exactly you are not understanding from it.

Comment: I can not get contents from the site http://ddth.com by the function file_get_contents and I wonder how they did. Details.

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon: They do that with a redirect. I think you want to learn more about file get contents, see http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/head-first-with-php-streams/

Answer (score 1):

you can use HTTP authentication to protect

```
$login = 'root';
$pass = '12345';

if(($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']!= $pass || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $login)|| !$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])
{
 header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Test auth"');
 header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
 echo 'Auth failed';
 exit;
}

else
{
 echo "ok";
 }
```

and can use curl to read

```
    $username = 'user';
    $password = 'password';
    $ip = $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"];      
    $browser_id = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; es-ES; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $browser_id);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ip);       
    $retValue = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

To extract information have code here [here](http://pastebin.com/wm3gjbsD)

Comment: if you would link the php manual for that feature wouldn't be bad I'd say.

Comment: No. If like that normal visitors can't enter the site. I wanto prevent bots only.